# program to print all decimal numbers from 0 to a given number in binary format

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm new to C.
I was writing a program to print all the decimal numbers from 0 to a given number(as provided by the user) but my output is not what I had expected. I don't understand what mistake is there in the program I've written....

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x,n;
    printf("Enter any number\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    n=x;
    printf("numbers in binary format\n");
    while(n!=0)
    {
        int num[8]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        int y[8]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        int i=7;
        while(x!=0)
        {
            y[i]=x%2;
            x=x/2;
            i=i-1;
        }
        while(i!=8)
        {
            printf("%d",y[i]);
            i=i+1;
        }
        printf("\n");
        n=n-1;
    }
}
```

Comment: what was your output? oO

Comment: You forgot a `x=n` at the beginning of the loop. And your code may crash for numbers higher than 255. And a note about style: All your `while` loops would be easier to read if they were `for` loops.

Comment: this program prints the numbers from a given number to 0 instead of from 0 to a given number

Comment: Thanks @mafso. I will take you suggestion. My code is working now..

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot to set the value of `x` inside the while loop this is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x,n;
    printf("Enter any number\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    n=x;
    printf("numbers in binary format\n");
    while(n!=0)
    {
        x=n;
        int y[8]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        int i=7;
        while(x!=0)
        {
            y[i]=x%2;
            x=x/2;
            i=i-1;
        }
        i=0;
        while(i!=8)
        {
            printf("%d",y[i]);
            i=i+1;
        }
        printf("\n");
        n=n-1;
    }
}
```

I have to add that the variable `num` isn't used.

Comment: also the other answer provided by epivav spoted another mistake, without that line the program will fail in some cases, my answer is fixed now

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your first loop

```
    while(x!=0)
    {
        y[i]=x%2;
        x=x/2;
        i=i-1;
    }
```

When this loop finishes, your i will *not* be 0 in most cases, and your second while loop is based on this assumption.

just put a

```
i = 0;
```

after your first loop. it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple method-

```
printf("numbers in binary format\n");
for(n=0;n<=x;n++)  // this loop will print the number 0 to x in binary format.
{
  for(i=31;i>=0;i--) // this is for 32 bit integer. if you are using 16 bit integer make i=15 in initialization.
  {
    if(n&(1<<i)) 
    printf("1");
    else
    printf("0");
  }
 printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value i is being decremented in the first loop and it is not reset to 0 after the loop.
Please set

i=0 after the loop and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

To convert from `unsigned int` (only 0 or positive numbers) to the corresponding string representation, you could do this:

```
char *bin(unsigned int number, char *result)
{
    unsigned int mask = 1 << ((sizeof(unsigned int) * 8) - 1);
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(unsigned int) * 8; i++)
    {
        if (number & mask)
        {
            result[i] = '1';

        }
        else
        {
            result[i] = '0';
        }

        number <<= 1;
    }

    result[i]='\0'; //Terminate the string

    return result;
}
```

In the beginning it creates `mask` as a number that is all zero, except the most significant bit.

Then it does a binary end of that mask with the most significant bit of the number to convert, and puts either `0` or `1` in the string.

Then it shifts the number to convert so that the most significant bit is lost, and the 2nd most significant is now the most significant, and goes on until the number is totally converted in the string.

In the end it terminates the string.

You could call it like this:

```
int main()
{
    int i, to;
    printf("Enter any number\n");
    scanf("%d", &to);
    char *result = calloc((sizeof(unsigned int) * 8) + 1, sizeof(char));

    for (i = 0; i <= to; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", bin(i, result));
    }

    free(result);

    return 0;
}
```